# Jolt transformation to concat arrays

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I want to use a jolt transformation to concatenate two lists

Input

```
{
    "listA": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "listB": [
        4,
        5
    ]
}
```

Jolt Spec

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "listA": "items",
        "listB": "items"
    }
}]
```

Desired Output:

```
{
  "items" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
}
```

I am getting a nested list. How can I get a flat list like in the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

```
[
   {
     "operation": "shift",
     "spec": {
       "listA": {
         "*": "items[]"
       },
       "listB": {
         "*": "items[]"
       }
     }
  }
]
```